# how to fix mod rewirte

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have problem with mod rewrite

i made htaccess to convert url from php to html

and every thing fine

but problem is some file i dont need to convert like form.php

this is my htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)form.php(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)sitemap\.xml(.*)$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s([^/]+)\.php\s
RewriteRule .* %1.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ $1.php
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://%{http_host} [R=301,L]
```

i dont need convert sitemap.xml and form.php

but i got error when i try to see file form.php

HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

what i can do?

Comment: Start by looking at the server's error log to see exactly what's causing the 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

Checking logs is the best place to start as Marc B suggests. You should enable more verbose mod_rewrite logging as so:

```
RewriteLog "/usr/local/var/apache/logs/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

Don't take the verbosity of the `RewriteLogLevel` higher than 3.

So, reading your rules, I think I may know what you mean. You should try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !form\.php$
```

I do not think Apache cares about the query string that may follow at the URL. There is a `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable you can use in addition to `%{REQUEST_URI}`. Unless you have some weird URLs that may have "php" in them, I presume that all of them will end with ".php".

Since "sitemap.xml" seems OK, it is likely the case that you should follow its example and escape out the period character (".")  the same way with "\."

A day later, I had some time to think about these rules.

```
# Use simpler rules, not all that jazz you prepend, appended.
# 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} form\.php$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} sitemap\.xml$ 
# If %{REQUEST_URI} matches either of the previous rule, 
# we skip a certain number of RewriteRules that follow. 
# If you add more rules, and need to skip more, you *need* to adjust this number.
RewriteRule . - [S=2]  

# Your original line reads:
#
# RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s([^/]+)\.php\s
#
# Using "%{THE_REQUEST}" variable means you are processing
# a string like this
#
# "GET /something.html HTTP/1.1"
#
# Did you really need the HTTP method and the protocol version?
# Do something simpler. Match the the "http://host/foo/bar/baz/" portion
# Then match the first part of the PHP file name. So, if URL ends in "something.php"
# The second parenthesis will match "something". Then append ".html" 

RewriteRule (^.*\/)([^/]+)(\.php)$   $1$2.html [R=301,L]

# **Then** you are trying to rewrite your HTML files to PHP? Why?
# In any case, do something similar as the last RewriteRule. 

RewriteRule (^.*\/)([^/]+)(\.html)$   $1$2.php [R=301,L]

# I do not understand RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200 at all
# I don't see you using this environmental variable later on in this
# snippet. Recommend the use of "PT" in case you have other stuff running
# that you want to send the rewrite target to be passed back to the 
# URL mapping engine. 

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [PT, QSA]

# You neglected to add the leading slash in this pattern
RewriteRule ^/index.php$ http://%{http_host} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: sorry i fix it its in form.php problem with mysql close so i fix it thx guys so match

Comment: problem now if i go to support.php is not convert url to support.html

why that?

Comment: To be honest, your directives are difficult to interpet. Maybe the thing to do is to create a specialized VirtualHost to test out your patterns. For me, the most general case is that you want to rewrite your HTML files to PHP. The simplest way: is to use something like `RewriteRule (.*)\.html $1.php [PT,L]` . This should do the trick in the general case. Get that to work first, then add in the rules to exclude what you need afterwards. Of course, since the directives may be sequential add them above the more general rule.